# Find the surface area on $z=y^2 + x^2$ below both $z=1$ and $z=\frac{x}{2}+y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do you find the surface area here? I only really understand when the graph is only below one plane not 2.

Comment: Your question is poorly worded.  What does it mean "surface area on $y^2 + x^2$"?

Comment: my bad i forgot to put z=

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The surface area of the paraboloid $z=y^2+x^2$ below the plane $z=1$ and the surface $z=\frac{xy}{2}$.

Comment: also another my bad the 2nd z=.5xy really is .5x+y

Comment: so the restated question is 

Find the surface area on z=y^2+x^2 below both z=1 and z=.5x+y       Thanks

Comment: also my apologies about bad wording this is my first time actually using this website although I have seen it before

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have difficulty visualizing the surface:

[image]

Or....

[image]

Comment: no its the limits for integration I have the graph